# AMQ webconsole does not work when using other contextname then admin

Tags: activemq-classic

I created a webconsole for AMQ project that runs on Tomcat. The site looks good, but when I try to change something, I get a 500 server error. The following stacktrace appears in de logfiles:

```
dec 30, 2014 4:22:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/default-amq-console] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Possible CSRF attack] with root cause
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Possible CSRF attack
at org.apache.activemq.web.handler.BindingBeanNameUrlHandlerMapping.getHandlerInternal(BindingBeanNameUrlHandlerMapping.java:59)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.getHandler(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:298)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getHandler(DispatcherServlet.java:1091)
etc, etc,etc
```

The URL for the webconsole is:

```
http://localhost:8080/default-amq-console.
```

When I use

```
http://localhost:8080/admin
```

everythings works fine.

Is it possible to use another contextname than admin, how can I configure it?

Comment: Changing the context name works just fine using the embedded Jetty server and webconsole with ActiveMQ. You seem to use some Tomcat stuff to load the console though. You should specify in more detail how your tomcat/webconsole webapp-configuration looks like since it's not standard.

Comment: It looks like a problem in Firefox with all my plugins. In IE it runs without problems, in Firefox without plugins also. I'll use the last one.

Answer (score 2):

Try to clear your browser cache.

It happened to me, and it works fine after I clear the cache. In case you don't like to clear cache and cookies because you don't like to login to your fav. sites again, you can try it in private mode (incognito for chrome).

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that my Firefox plugin blocked the cookies. So it has nothing to do with the context name.

Answer (score 1):

It's a cookies issue. On my chrome, even if the "Allow local data to be set" was enabled under cookies settings, it didn't work.
To let it works I've added an exception in cookie managment allowing the specific address of AMQ console

Answer (score 1):

Use Firefox browser will fix this problem.

Comment: This fixed it for me as well. Interesting effect!